# "recognised by _ as _" or "recognised as _ by _"

Tags: word-order

Which is correct ordering of descriptors between "as" and "by" with regards to "being recognised"?

Example sentences:

> IEEE 754 has been **recognised as** de facto standard **by** all programmers.

or

> IEEE 754 has been **recognised by** all programmers **as** de facto standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it matters semantically.
The first sentence slightly emphasises the recognition by all programmers, whereas the second sentence slightly emphasises the fact that IEEE 754 is the standard.

Note: I would write "*the*/*a* de facto standard".

Comment: I agree with you on both counts but it also makes sense to say "_a_ de facto standard" in some circumstances. "Recognised as de facto standard" however is definitely wrong.

Comment: @BoldBen Good point, I was indeed misled by the idea that since it is *a* standard, it must be *the* standard :) Thanks, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Prepositional phrases](https://www.thoughtco.com/arrange-and-rearrange-prepositional-phrases-1689685) like the ones in your example are often interchangeable.  Some orderings may have different implications (@Joachim is right that the phrase you put first receives a bit more emphasis), but grammatically both sentences are fine.